# Unable to Draw MapView on Fragments

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting an error as mentioned below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)' on a
>   null object reference

Please help me to resolve it and advise where I am wrong. Please find the complete snapshot for the error below the code.

```
    public class FragmentFriends extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static final String MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY";
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    @BindView(R.id.mapView)
    MapView mapView;
    private View viewFriends;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewFriends = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
        initGoogleMaps(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return viewFriends;
    }

    private void initGoogleMaps(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }
        mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mapView.onStart();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mapView.onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        mapView.onLowMemory();
        super.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

Error Screenshot

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
        at com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio.fragments.FragmentFriends.initGoogleMaps(FragmentFriends.java:43)
        at com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio.fragments.FragmentFriends.onCreateView(FragmentFriends.java:31)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:299)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:669)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:631)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:612)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:3326)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1767)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1760)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1720)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:2138)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:2326)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Comment: i think you are passing a null data in . 
`initGoogleMaps(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Add this function in your code to respond:***

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapViewBundle == null) {
        mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
        outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
    }

    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `initGoogleMaps(savedInstanceState);` to `onViewCreated`.

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Bundle mapBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapBundle == null) {
        mapBundle = new Bundle();
    }
    initGoogleMaps(mapBundle);
}

private void initGoogleMaps(Bundle mapBundle) {
    mapView.onCreate(mapBundle);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Looking at the documentation indeed `onSaveInstanceState()` was missing:

```java
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    if (mapViewBundle != null) {
        outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

}
```

However `mapView.onCreate(bundle)` expects a non-nullable Bundle and therefore the above was updated to pass a non-nullable Bundle to initialize the map.

Comment: 2020-05-08 13:51:48.584 19289-19289/com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio, PID: 19289
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
        at com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio.fragments.FragmentFriends.initGoogleMaps(FragmentFriends.java:49)
        at com.bhagatsoftinc.trackio.fragments.FragmentFriends.onViewCreated(FragmentFriends.java:41)